# NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 cannot access java.lang Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: android, netbeans, error-handling, java.lang.class

I need help with android project inside NetBeans.  I Just opened project which is created in NetBeans and I have some issues with "cannot access java.lang
  Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath"
This is sample of one my file which have issues:

```
package Helpers;
import PreglednikLogika.Clanak;
import android.content.Context;
```

The first line `package Helpers;` is underlined and produce `"cannot access java.lang
  Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath"`

I am new with netbeans and I tried some fixes but not success. Can somebody help me ? I think this is adding reference library or something like that issue... but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found what the problem was.

1. I updated this path to my correct path `sdk.dir=E:\\ANDROID\\Eclipse371\\android-sdk` in project file `local.properties`.
2. I updated `project.properties` file `# Project target.target=android-8`, to target 8 I had 7  before that obviously does not supported in this version of SDK.

and I successfully build my project  :)

Comment: Is this question about android.?

Answer (score 21):

The project has an old hotspot, in Netbeans:

- Right click the project
- properties
- libraries
- update "Java Platform"

Not exclusive to Android, this happened to me while trying to compile a very old project.

Comment: I know this is old, but this helped me to get to the answer, thanks a lot :)